# what is use of componentName.test.js file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

many times I see *.test.js file in react projects like a template and react example project.
can someone tell me what is motive of this file is?

Comment: Are you looking for a more sophisticated answer than _for testing_?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's called unit testing. Whenever you create any component, you can write test cases for that component's expected output.

For each file, you have to add *.test.js. So, react can get that file and perform the particular test cases.

For more info, you can check react official [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html).